# Is it possible to access the data in the temp table after procedure execution in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a stored procedure inside which I am declaring a temporary table

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.temp_table
        ( 
        query_id                INTEGER ,
        Query                 varchar(8000)       
        )     .
```

Is it possible to access the data in the temp table after sp execution? Requirement is to put my dynamic sql in temp table and after execution figure out what query is being executed in stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

If the DGTT has "on commit preserve rows" and "on rollback preserve rows" and if the session remains open then the contents of the DGTT are accessible to that session after an sproc returns (and before the sproc runs again, if the DGTT has 'with replace').